# Equations numbering

Tags: equations, numbering, counters, utf8, setcounter

In a tex document I would like to number the equations like all the rest. Instead equations seem to have their own numbering. Here is an example:
right after "Remark 4.5" I have "Equation (3)". I would prefer to have "Equation (4.6)" instead.

I already tried to add a `\stepcounter{thm}` before all remarks, theorems, propositions, ecc...
but it did not work. Is there a way to settle this issue?

I enclose below the first part of my tex file. Thank you very much.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumerate, amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amscd,mathrsfs,hyperref}

\usepackage{colortbl,float,longtable,xcolor,booktabs,bookmark}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\newcommand{\V}[1]{\mathcal{V}\!\left({#1}\right)}

\newcommand{\gap}{\hspace{0.5em}}

\newcommand{\vgap}{\vspace{0.25em}}

\newcommand{\padding}{\rule[-1.45ex]{0pt}{0.2em}\gap}

\newcommand{\oddrow}{\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}}

\newcommand{\evnrow}{}

\newlength{\matrixheight}

\newcommand{\calculatepadding}[1]{\settoheight{\matrixheight}{\hbox{#1}}{#1}}

\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem*{thmA}{Theorem A}

\newtheorem*{thmB}{Theorem B}

\newtheorem*{thmC}{Theorem C}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\newtheorem{pro}[thm]{Proposition}

\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}

\newtheorem{Lemma}[thm]{Lemma}

\newtheorem{Proposition}[thm]{Proposition}

\newtheorem{Corollary}[thm]{Corollary}

\newtheorem{Conjecture}[thm]{Conjecture}

\newtheorem*{thm*}{Theorem}

\newtheorem*{theoremn}{Theorem}

\newtheorem*{conjecturen}{Conjecture}

\newtheorem{Claim}[thm]{Claim}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{dfn}[thm]{Definition}

\newtheorem{claim}[thm]{Claim}

\newtheorem{exa}[thm]{Example}

\newtheorem{prb}[thm]{Problem}

\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}

\newtheorem{que}[thm]{Question}

\newtheorem{Notation}[thm]{Notation}

\newtheorem{Problem}[thm]{Problem}

\newtheorem{Construction}[thm]{Construction}

\newtheorem{Definition}[thm]{Definition}

\newtheorem{Remark}[thm]{Remark}

\newtheorem{Remarks}[thm]{Remarks}

\newtheorem{Question}[thm]{Question}

\newtheorem{Example}[thm]{Example}

\newtheorem{Assumption}[thm]{Assumptions}

\newtheorem{say}[thm]{}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really understand why you define similar environments multiple times (`claim`/`Claim`, `lem`/`Lemma`), so here just a reduced version of your code:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{pro}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\makeatletter
\let\c@equation\c@thm
\makeatother
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
Normal normal normal normal normal normal
\begin{thm}
Theorem theorem theorem theorem theorem
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
Theorem theorem theorem theorem theorem theorem
\end{thm}
Normal normal normal normal normal normal
\begin{pro}
Proposition proposition proposition proposition
\end{pro}
Normal normal normal normal normal normal
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
Normal normal normal normal normal normal
\begin{lem}
Lemma lemma lemma lemma lemma lemma lemma
\end{lem}

\section{Bar}
Normal normal normal normal normal normal
\begin{thm}
Theorem theorem theorem theorem theorem theorem
\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]